# How to disable dropdowns and buttons based on the value of a column in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a table with a set of columns fetching values from a database along with a dropdown and button in each row. Depending on the value of one of the columns(YEAR), the dropdown (SALARY) and button (UPDATE) need to be disabled.

I tried two different approaches using Javascript and Jquery. But both don't seem to work.

1) I tried triggering an event on pageload using Javascript

```
<body onload="dropdownDisabler();">
```

Javascript part:

```
function dropdownDisabler()
{
    if ($("#YEAR").val() >= 2005)
    {
                    $("#SALARY").enabled=false;
                    $("#UPDATE").enabled=false;
    }

}
```

2) I tried matching all the YEAR column elements which have a certain criteria using JQuery:

```
if($('#YEAR').val() >= 2005)
{
     $(this).find("#SALARY").prop('disabled',true);
     $(this).find("#UPDATE").prop('disabled',true);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over all the rows, check the value of the year and then set the disabled property on the `select` and `button` element in that row:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#UpdateSalary tbody tr").each(function( index ) {

        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.children("td:first").text() >= 2005 ) {
           $this.find("select, button").prop("disabled", true);
        }

    });

});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dHH4U/)

Note that since you have multiple rows (I assume), you should not use IDs for your elements, [ID's must be unique on each document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2). You could use classes though to more easily target your elements within each row, e.g. `<td class="year">2004</td>`